# How to merge big csv-files and convert them into one xml-file

Tags: c#, xml, csv

I'm pretty new to programming in c# and I have some problems to process a lot of data in several csv-files into one xml-file.

The csv files I have look like the following:

```
"ID","NODE","PROCESS_STATE","TIME_STAMP","PREV_TIME_STAMP","CALCULATED"
206609474,2175,47,31.03.2015 00:01:25,31.03.2015 00:01:24,1
206609475,2175,47,31.03.2015 00:02:25,31.03.2015 00:01:25,1
206609476,2175,47,31.03.2015 00:03:25,31.03.2015 00:02:25,1
```

In a first step I remove all entries that aren't important for my calculations (e.g. I remove all files that don't contain specific dates) and then save each file again.

The second step is to merge all those prepared files (~ 100) into one big csv-file.

Until here everything works pretty good and fast.

The last step is to convert the csv-file into an xml-file of the following format:

```
<data-set>   
  <PDA_DATA>
    <ID>484261933</ID>
    <NODE>2190</NODE>
    <PROCESS_STATE>18</PROCESS_STATE>
    <PREV_TIME_STAMP>05.05.2016 22:53:41</PREV_TIME_STAMP>
  </PDA_DATA>   
  <PDA_DATA>
    <ID>484261935</ID>
    <NODE>2190</NODE>
    <PROCESS_STATE>47</PROCESS_STATE>
    <PREV_TIME_STAMP>06.05.2016 00:44:17</PREV_TIME_STAMP>   
  </PDA_DATA>
</data-set>
```

As you can see I remove elements ("TIME_STAMP", "CALCULATED") and further more I also remove all entries where the entry "TIME_STAMP" is equal to "PREV_TIME_STAMP". I'm doing this with the following code:

```
string[] csvlines = File.ReadAllLines("All_Machines.csv");

XElement xml = new XElement("data-set",
    from str in csvlines
    let columns = str.Split(',')
    select new XElement("PDA_DATA",
        new XElement("ID", columns[0]),
        new XElement("NODE", columns[2]),
        new XElement("PROCESS_STATE", columns[5]),
        new XElement("TIME_STAMP", columns[6]),
        new XElement("PREV_TIME_STAMP", columns[9]),
        new XElement("CALCULATED", columns[10])));

// Remove unneccessray elements

xml.Elements("PDA_DATA")
    .Where(e => 
        e.Element("TIME_STAMP").Value.Equals(e.Element("PREV_TIME_STAMP").Value))
            .Remove();   // Remove entries with duration = 0

xml.Elements("PDA_DATA").Elements("TIME_STAMP").Remove();
xml.Elements("PDA_DATA").Elements("PREV_PROCESS_STATE").Remove();
xml.Elements("PDA_DATA").Elements("CALCULATED").Remove();
xml.Save("All_Machines.xml");
```

And here is my problem. If I exclude the line where I remove Elements where TimeStamp equals PrevTimeStamp everything works pretty good and fast.
But with this command, it takes a lot of time and does only work with small csv-files.

I have no knowledge about resource-efficient programming, so I'd be really glad if someone of you could tell me where the problem is or how to do that better.

Comment: Maybe you could check out PLINQ to see if you can run the linq queries in parallel https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Couldn't find anything there. But I tried to create a scond XML file where only elements are added which fullfill m where-condition. This seems to be much faster and I can process 100MB csv-files now which was impossible before!

Comment: Are you sure the code and csv you posted above create the given xml? When I run that code against the csv my xml only has 1 `PDA_DATA` element and the elements in that contain the strings `ID`, `NODE` etc ... Please post a complete and recreatable example

Comment: Sorry the original csv has a lot more entries. I deleted a few of them so its easier to see here. But i forgot to adapt the columns in: new XElement("Node", columns[x])

Comment: No problem, but please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting, and if you have found a solution to the problem you should post it as an answer and then accept when you can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works out much faster:

```
string[] csvlines = File.ReadAllLines("All_Machines.csv");

    XElement xml = new XElement("data-set",
        from str in csvlines
        let columns = str.Split(',')
        select new XElement("PDA_DATA",
            new XElement("ID", columns[0]),
            new XElement("NODE", columns[1]),
            new XElement("PROCESS_STATE", columns[2]),
            new XElement("TIME_STAMP", columns[3]),
            new XElement("PREV_TIME_STAMP", columns[4]),
            new XElement("CALCULATED", columns[5]),
                             )   
                            );

    // Remove unneccessray elements

        XElement xml2 = new XElement("data-set",                                       
                from el in xml.Elements() 
                where (el.Element("TIME_STAMP").Value != (el.Element("PREV_TIME_STAMP").Value))
                select el
                );

       xml2.Elements("PDA_DATA").Elements("TIME_STAMP").Remove();
       xml2.Elements("PDA_DATA").Elements("PREV_PROCESS_STATE").Remove();
       xml2.Elements("PDA_DATA").Elements("CALCULATED").Remove();
       xml2.Save("All_Machines.xml");
```

Still not perfect for csv-file-sizes over 150 MB.. Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

With [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/) - an open source framework, you can read and write CSV/Xml large files quickly with few lines of code as below

```
using (var csv = new ChoCSVReader("NodeData.csv").WithFirstLineHeader(true)
    .WithFields("ID", "NODE", "PROCESS_STATE", "PREV_TIME_STAMP"))
{
    using (var xml = new ChoXmlWriter("NodeData.xml").WithXPath("data-set/PDA_DATA"))
        xml.Write(csv);
}
```

The output xml look like

```
<data-set>
  <PDA_DATA>
    <ID>206609474</ID>
    <NODE>2175</NODE>
    <PROCESS_STATE>47</PROCESS_STATE>
    <PREV_TIME_STAMP>31.03.2015 00:01:25</PREV_TIME_STAMP>
  </PDA_DATA>
  <PDA_DATA>
    <ID>206609475</ID>
    <NODE>2175</NODE>
    <PROCESS_STATE>47</PROCESS_STATE>
    <PREV_TIME_STAMP>31.03.2015 00:02:25</PREV_TIME_STAMP>
  </PDA_DATA>
  <PDA_DATA>
    <ID>206609476</ID>
    <NODE>2175</NODE>
    <PROCESS_STATE>47</PROCESS_STATE>
    <PREV_TIME_STAMP>31.03.2015 00:03:25</PREV_TIME_STAMP>
  </PDA_DATA>
</data-set>
```

Disclosure: I'm the author of this library